# how to get access to genotypes and phenotypes used for a GWAS

Tags: genomics, gwas, deep-learning

I'm a master's student working on genomic prediction of complex traits using deep learning.
i'm looking for a dataset of human genotypes and phenotypes that has been used for a GWAS. 
The only thing i can get from the gwas i found is the summary statistics not the raw data. 
Does anyone know if it's possible to get such data (for free ) for a research project? 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

- dbGaP - https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gap/ - in case you are searching for supporting datasets I leave its entry in [BiŌkeanós](http://biokeanos.com/source/Database%20of%20Genotypes%20and%20Phenotypes)
- https://www.ddbj.nig.ac.jp/jga/ - the access might be a bit more complicated.
- https://www.internationalgenome.org, not particularly large, in their FAQ they state that the individuals sequenced have not self-reported any diseases - perhaps you might want to add those with to your negative set.  Again, its entry in [BiŌkeanós](https://biokeanos.com/source/The%20International%20Genome%20Sample%20Resource).

If you are looking for more comprehensive information, you could try biobanks - e.g. https://www.ukbiobank.ac.uk. These are usually open (or reasonably priced) for research but the approval process can take time.

A side note - some of GWAS catalogues will have a link to the study where the association originated from, [e.g. here](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/gwas/studies/GCST005312). You can sometimes find the datasource there.